# pingtest.net gives "Packet Loss Test Error"

Tags: ping

This is what I get when trying the pingtest.net on Ubuntu 11.10

I don't have any firewall running on my router. Is there a firewall running on Ubuntu that I don't know about?

[image: Error message]

Comment: [Here is their FAQ](http://pingtest.net/help.php#q6) on this issue, check that you have Java installed and ports 5060 and 8080 are open outbound for both TCP and UDP. Or, just forget Pingtest and use the far superior [M-Lab](http://www.measurementlab.net/measurement-lab-tools) tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most consumer routers also perform [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT).  They also normally ignore pings by default.  You either can configure the router to respond to pings, or you may be able to configure the DMZ to forward the ping ( and everything else ) to your computer so it can respond.

Comment: It was basically that. Worked like a charm. 
Thanks!

Comment: The test says that it's "Enable to test packet loss" but still, it goes with the test and finish it. Any work around this? is there any reason Ubuntu prevents it to test packet loss? since I'm on DMZ now and no firewall is enabled.

Comment: @AdameDoe, what?  You said it worked like a charm.

Comment: The test gives a result, but I'm still having a ~ Packet loss test failed. 

Here's a pic ~ 

![Pingtest result](http://i.imgur.com/wCLml.png)